# How does pushy keep the socket open on Android?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, pushy

We're currently evaluating a push notification service for our iOS and Android apps. Our two favourites are Firebase and [Pushy](https://pushy.me/). Pushy doesn't use Firebase under the hood, but rather open and maintain their own socket connection.
I was wondering which technology Pushy is using under the hood to be able to provide near real-time PNs without having a background service started that is drowning the devices battery and is not prone to get killed by the system.

Comment: Pushy uses a persistent MQTT connection under the hood: https://support.pushy.me/hc/en-us/articles/360043864271-What-is-MQTT-

Comment: Thanks @EladNava. I'm aware of the MQTT connection. But this doesn't answer my question. Why isn't the connection closed at some point by the system?

Comment: It's an excellent question, seems impossible to me